# Direct launch from iPad crashes the app, Xcode launch is fine

Tags: ios, debugging

My app is running fine when I launch from Xcode. But when I launch the same app from iPad by clicking its icon, it crashes immediately. How do I go about debugging this? Are there any crash logs that I can look at? Note that this version of the app is not yet released on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the crash logs by going to `Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data`

Comment: There is nothing for today's date in those logs, although I have run it multiple times today when it crashed at launch.

Answer (score 0):

To see the logs connect your device back to Xcode, then on the Xcode menu go to `Window -> Devices` -> Select your device -> `View Device Logs`